# How solve the equation $x^{4}-y^{4}= 80z^{4}$ for x and y odd integers, and z integer

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Let x and y be odd integers, and let z be an integer. How solve the equation $x^{4}-y^{4}= 80z^{4}$?

Comment: All triplets of the form $(3a,a,a)$ are solutions.

Comment: Is $z$ given, or are you trying to find all triplets $(x,y,z)$ of integers satisfying $x^4-y^4 = 80z^4$?

Comment: All triplets of form $(a, \pm a, 0)$ are also trivially solutions.